# Can't use transitions in kv lang

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

App code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import FadeTransition<br/>
kv = '''
ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    screen1:
    screen2:
<screen1>:
    name: 'one'
    Button:
        text: 'Hello!'
        on_release: app.root.current = 'two'
<screen2>:
    name: 'two'
    Button:
        text: 'Hello2'
        on_release: app.root.current = 'one'
'''<br/>
class screen1(Screen):
    pass
class screen2(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass
class test23(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
        <br/>
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test23().run()
```

Every time I execute it I have the following traceback. What's wrong with it?

```
 runfile('/home/pc/python and kivy/test23.py', wdir='/home/pc/python and kivy')<br/>
 Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module><br/>
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile<br/>
     execfile(filename, namespace)<br/>
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile<br/>
     builtins.execfile(filename, *where)<br/>
   File "/home/pc/python and kivy/test23.py", line 42, in <module><br/>
     test23().run()<br/>
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()<br/>
   File "/home/pc/python and kivy/test23.py", line 39, in build
     return Builder.load_string(kv)<br/>
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1921, in load_string<br/>
     self._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)<br/>
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 2130, in _apply_rule
     e), cause=tb)<br/>
 kivy.lang.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 3:
 ..<br/>
       1:<br/>
       2:ScreenManagement:<br/>
 >>    3:    transition: FadeTransition()<br/>
       4:    screen1:<br/>
       5:    screen2:<br/>
 ..<br/>
 BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 3:
 ..<br/>
       1:<br/>
       2:ScreenManagement:<br/>
 >>    3:    transition: FadeTransition()<br/>
       4:    screen1:<br/>
       5:    screen2:<br/>
 ..<br/>
 NameError: name 'FadeTransition' is not defined<br/>
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1742, in create_handler<br/>
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list<br/>
   File "<string>", line 3, in <module><br/><br/>

   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 2115, in _apply_rule
     rctx['ids'])<br/>
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1747, in create_handler
     cause=tb)<br/>
```

Comment: This question is very unclear at present and not focussed on a specific issue. Try and explain what you have tried so far to fix the various errors thrown up by the compiler and where exactly you are struggling.

Comment: edit question and use button `{}` to format code.

Comment: @Sparky The question isn't unclear, the author is just confused, because this is specifically framework-related way of handling imports in framework's own language. Error is clear enough though = `NameError: name <something> is not defined`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Transitions aren't widgets, nor properties, therefore they aren't imported by default while creating the enviroment for parsing the `.kv` file or `kv` string, so you'll need to import it at the top of the `.kv` file / string.

Example:

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
```

Comment: Keeweusr:   sorry about not being specific. I'm script kiddie and a big time noob. So thank you for ur response

Comment: @PoornaChandra I guess they downvoted you because of the formatting now, but the better made question, the less downvotes :)

Answer (score 2):

At the top of the kv file you need an import.   To get the transition it will be

#: import sm kivy.uix.screenmanager

ScreenManager:
    transition: sm.FadeTransition()
    screen1:
    screen2:
    ....

This is how I do it,  and this works for all transitions a full documentation can be found at https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html

I am using python 2.7 and kivy 1.10.0